# Is approximately 50% memory always used in Cache?

Tags: hard-drive, memory

[image]

Not a single application is used at the moment, but around 50% of the total physical; memory available is showing as cached.

I have 4GB + 4GB memory =  RAM

What does that mean?

Is this the reason my performance is poor? Are there any fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half your memory is used (Windows 64-bit will use 3 - 4 GB of memory at all times). Half is available for use which is about right. So memory does not seem to be the cause of poor performance. CPU says 15% which is OK. So look at disk usage and see if there are issue of constant disk usage

On a good machine, memory usage will stay at 4 GB when lightly loaded even after upgrading to 16 GB. Disk error 1962 when booting can be a faulty disk. Use the Manufacturer's Drive test application to determine if there are errors

Comment: Thanks. I will run  a disk check.